Why `(HP)(A)->H` does NOT match `[^a-zA-Z0-9]A[^a-zA-Z0-9]` in Regex in Kotlin but it matches in https://regexr.com/?
Question:
I get this issue for several hours.
Why (HP)(A)->H does NOT match [^a-zA-Z0-9]A[^a-zA-Z0-9] in Kotlin?
regexr website
Expression1
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]A[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g
Text
(HP)(A)->H
Result
(A)

Expression2
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]A[^a-zA-Z0-9]/gy
Text
(HP)(A)->H
Result
no result



Regex class in Kotlin

In VSC
Code
test1.kt
fun exactlyMatch(target:String,entryForReplacement:Pair<String,String>){
    val nonLetterOrDigit = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
    val (key,value) = entryForReplacement
    val keyRegexString = nonLetterOrDigit + key + nonLetterOrDigit
    val keyRegEx = Regex(keyRegexString)
    val matched = keyRegEx.matches(target)
 println("target:${target},key:${key},value:${value},keyRegEx.pattern:${keyRegEx.pattern},matched:${matched}")
}
fun main(){
    val target = "(HP)(A)->H"
    val mapForReplacement : Map<String,String> = mapOf("A" to "Aura:Green","HP" to "HP:75","H" to "healthStatus")
    val mapForReplacementList = mapForReplacement.toList()
    println("mapForReplacementList:${mapForReplacementList}")

    var entryForReplacement: Pair<String,String>
    for(entryForReplacement in mapForReplacementList){
        exactlyMatch(target,entryForReplacement)
    }   
}

Result after execution
    PS C:\Users\{USERNAME}\OneDrive\桌面\TibaMe\Kotlin\THE BIG NERD RANCH GUIDE\CH3> kotlinc test1.kt -include-runtime -d test1.jar
    PS C:\Users\{USERNAME}\OneDrive\桌面\TibaMe\Kotlin\THE BIG NERD RANCH GUIDE\CH3> java -jar test1.jar 
    mapForReplacementList:[(A, Aura:Green), (HP, HP:75), (H, healthStatus)]
    target:(HP)(A)->H,key:A,value:Aura:Green,keyRegEx.pattern:[^a-zA-Z0-9]A[^a-zA-Z0-9],matched:false
    target:(HP)(A)->H,key:HP,value:HP:75,keyRegEx.pattern:[^a-zA-Z0-9]HP[^a-zA-Z0-9],matched:false
    target:(HP)(A)->H,key:H,value:healthStatus,keyRegEx.pattern:[^a-zA-Z0-9]H[^a-zA-Z0-9],matched:false

[]
(https://i.sstatic.net/oJ2amRsA.png)

In Kotlin online active shell
Code
fun exactlyMatch(target:String,entryForReplacement:Pair<String,String>){
    val nonLetterOrDigit = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
    val (key,value) = entryForReplacement
    val keyRegexString = nonLetterOrDigit + key + nonLetterOrDigit
    val keyRegEx = Regex(keyRegexString)
    val matched = keyRegEx.matches(target)
      println("target:${target},key:${key},value:${value},keyRegEx.pattern:${keyRegEx.pattern},matched:${matched}")
}

fun main(){
    val target = "(HP)(A)->H"
    val mapForReplacement : Map<String,String> = mapOf("A" to "Aura:Green","HP" to "HP:75","H" to "healthStatus")
    val mapForReplacementList = mapForReplacement.toList()
    println("mapForReplacementList:${mapForReplacementList}")

    var entryForReplacement: Pair<String,String>
    for(entryForReplacement in mapForReplacementList){
        exactlyMatch(target,entryForReplacement)
    }   
}

main()

Result after execution
    mapForReplacementList:[(A, Aura:Green), (HP, HP:75), (H, healthStatus)]
    target:(HP)(A)->H,key:A,value:Aura:Green,keyRegEx.pattern:[^a-zA-Z0-9]A[^a-zA-Z0-9],matched:false
    target:(HP)(A)->H,key:HP,value:HP:75,keyRegEx.pattern:[^a-zA-Z0-9]HP[^a-zA-Z0-9],matched:false
    target:(HP)(A)->H,key:H,value:healthStatus,keyRegEx.pattern:[^a-zA-Z0-9]H[^a-zA-Z0-9],matched:false

[]


Other info
IDE: VSC
Kotlin plugin: []
What I tried?

I have test these expression in regexr website.

Kotlin docs


Also, I visit Kotlin API reference to know how to use them.

Regex class
Regex class

matches method in Regex class



What is the "y" in Expression 2, /[^a-zA-Z0-9]A[^a-zA-Z0-9]/gy? Note that the site underlines the y with a red line, suggesting that it is an error.

Note that matches requires the whole string to match, not just a substring. In your case, the regexp does not match the entire input because there are too many characters either side of the A but you are only looking for 1 character on either side.

The documentation of Regex.matches that you linked states the following:

Indicates whether the regular expression matches the entire input.

So keyRegEx.matches(target) will only be true if the entire target string matches the regex, which is not the case here, as you can confirm on the regexr website.
If you want to find a match within a bigger string, you can use find instead.
